# myHttpInterceptor Factory causes "Circular dependency found: factory1 <- $http <- factory2"

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Well I have two factories: **auth_service.js** and **user_service.js**

What I'm trying to accomplish:

### user_service.js

It will be like a session manager, it will store user data info so it's available across the app. Also when the app runs for the first time it does an ajax request to the server to check if there's a logged user, although I think that the app only does that on the index page. (that will be another question)

### auth_Service.js

This would be responsible for some sort of user actions encapsulation, like login, logout and isLoggedIn

Here's the plunker with: [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/L7Q3IiQvqAda81q8a5id?p=preview)

Although in this plunker I only get

`Circular dependency found: $http <- UserService`

At my app this is what I get:

`Circular dependency found: UserService <- $http <- AuthenticationService`

The problem is somewhere on my interceptor, since I'm intercepting for 401 and I inject UserService to logout user in case of a 401

Comment: You should construct your plunker in a way it represents the whole problem, reproducing the error you got, and not just for showing snippets of your code.

Comment: I tried to create another plunker (http://plnkr.co/edit/gxd4qAOjOTl3ljpcqyk4?p=preview) representing your case and if I did it right there is no errors with your code. So perhaps you didn't show us some important pieces. From the error message you mentioned it seems that $http service depends on your UserService, which is very strange and is not shown on the code you posted.

Comment: I'm creating a plunker with all my code, the problem is how can I simulate the $http requests to my laravel4 localhost?

Comment: You can use `angular-mock` to mock $httpBackend. This is a very handy technique for development, so called 'backendless development'. For example see this - http://michalostruszka.pl/blog/2013/05/27/easy-stubbing-out-http-in-angularjs-for-backend-less-frontend-development/

Comment: I've updated my question with more info

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all `responseInterceptors` are deprecated. I highly recommend to use `interceptors`. They are even easier to use, imho.

Your assumption is correct. One possible way to get over this is using events.

In your interceptor you inject `$rootScope` instead of `UserService`. Then instead of calling the service's method you emit an event, e.g. `$rootScope.emit('unsetUser')`.

In your `UserService` you listen to that event: `$rootScope.on('unsetUser', function() {`.

That way the `$http` service has no idea of the `UserService`, but they still can communicate.

Another solution would be to create some kind of intermediary service, that is injected in both. The `UserService`would then register itself as observer and the interceptor can call a method that in turn notifies the `UserService`.